# update SQL rows with multidimensional array as source

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

**Goal:**
I want to update existing entries in my SQL table [dbo.properties]. The SQL command is executed in PHP. The PHP file again receives an array, as new data source. This array contains a unique *ID*, *propertyName* and the actual *value*.

**Problem:**
How do I loop, in SQL, through an array and make sure to update the values at the correct point?

My SQL table look like:

```
[id] as [int] increments by DB
[property] as [varchar(50)]
[value] as [varchar(50)]
```

The passed array look like:

```
0: Object {id:'30', property:'sugar', value:'20g'}
1: Object {id:'37', property:'salt', value:'10g'}
2: Object {id:'38', property:'chocolate', value:'120g'}
```

I know how to do it with single data or to delete multiple values with a list. But I its tough to find anything similar for my case. Especually as I need to update all in one query and the amount of rows is dynamic. Means it could be that only one item is updated or 10.

**Pseudo SQL query for better understand**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [updateProperties]
  BEGIN TRY 
    UPDATE properties SET 
    // Somehow iterate through array
    property = ('array[Pos][Entry1]'),
    value = ('array[Pos][Entry2]')
    WHERE id = ('array[Pos][Entry0]')
  COMMIT TRANSACTION [updateProperties]
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [updateProperties]
  END CATCH;
```

Comment: That looks like JSON; if so then SQL Server has had support for JSON since SQL Server 2016. Are you using a supported version of SQL Sevrer?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Then, assuming that is JSON, have a look at `OPENJSON`.

Comment: @Larnu how does it help me to loop within a update statement? I json_encode the array, actually for a better format. Still thanks for your input Larnu.

Comment: So it's not JSON? SQL Server doesn't have an array data type, so how are you getting said data to SQL Server then? If it's not JSON, perhaps what you *actually* want is a table type parameter. Seems like ou should actually be including details of is the programming language you are using too, as an array has no context from a SQL Server perspective; there's no such thing as an array in T-SQL.

Comment: Good point, I am passing the array as string for now. I used the same approach for a different query, where I implode the string and update certain values. Which works, so I had hope this could work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass this in as a proper JSON array, you can use `OPENJSON` to join to your table

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
  {"id":30, "property":"sugar", "value":"20g"},
  {"id":37, "property":"salt", "value":"10g"},
  {"id":38, "property":"chocolate", "value":"120g"}
]';

UPDATE p
SET property = j.property,
    value = j.value
FROM properties p
JOIN OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    id int,
    [property] varchar(50),
    [value] varchar(50)
  ) j ON j.id = p.id;
```

You can use `MERGE` if you want to update existing and insert new rows.

On a side note, I would advise you not to store `value` as a `varchar`. Instead, split it into `amount` and `unit`.